# How to construct an hexagon that has sides of two different specific lengths in the order of ababab, opposing sides are parallel

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I'm building a three legged sculpture stand. I would like to construct a hexagon in which:

- Every other side is of equal specific lengths  (Lengths of sides: *a b a b a b*).
- Opposing sides are parallel.

I hope the above summarises in words what I want to do. It should look approximately like this:

[image: A hexagon]

But the short respectivly long sides should be of specific lenghts, in my case the short sides should be 45 and the long sides 280. How can I construct that?

I am drawing in a cad-program and have constructed this in the way below, but I'm also interested in construction on paper.

[image]

#### My research so far

The angle sum of a hexagon is 720°, so each side is 120°. In the cad-program I can easily draw the figure by starting with a line of length 45, then draw a connected line of length 280 at angle 120° to the first line and so on. But on paper, using a goniometer, this wouldn't be very exact.

Comment: One approach: Start with an equilateral triangle of side length $45+280+45$ and chop off 3 equilateral triangles of side length 45 from the vertices.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don’t think it can be done easier than that, so I’d be happy to accept that as an answer. BTW the way the stand works great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach: Start with an equilateral triangle of side length $45+280+45$
and chop off 3 equilateral triangles of side length 45 from the vertices.